# Navbar and text not properly aligning

Tags: html, navbar

I am trying to set a fixed navbar that has a scrolling effect. Logo, links are on the left hand side and the sign up and log in are aligned on the right hand sign with icon. when I try to run the code, its not looking like it suppose to. I've tried a few ideas and looked up every idea and template design and used plenty of references and I am still stuck.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title> Kappa Delta Rho - Psi Beta </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Fixed Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark" style=" background-color: #00008B">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> KDR LOGO </a>
            </div>
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"> Welcome </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> History </a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- End of Fixed Navigation -->




    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try remove fixed-top.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <title> Kappa Delta Rho - Psi Beta </title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- Fixed Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-dark" style=" background-color: #00008B">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> KDR LOGO </a>
            </div>
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#"> Welcome </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> About </a></li>
                <li><a href="#"> History </a></li>
            </ul>
            
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- End of Fixed Navigation -->
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>



    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was able to adjust the code, I was able to format Welcome, about, and history.  I was also able to align Sign Up and Login, however the icon will not show up.